# Reading file in jar archive

Tags: jar, executable-jar

In my maven project, I have some csv files in src/main/resources/data folder which I am reading as follows:

```
private static final String FILE_PATH_ROOT= "src/main/resources/data/";

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH_ROOT+ 
fileName),   SEPERATOR_CHARACTER);
```

This approach works when I run my program from eclipse. But when I build a jar and execute it, I get the message that the system could not find the specifed data. In the jar file, the files are simply in the data folder inside the main jar archive. How can I fix this so that the files are read correctly?

Comment: Try placing them in `C:/temp` and change the location.

Answer (score 0):

If the file ends up inside the Jar file (or within the classpath) you will probably have to use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

From the InputStream create a InputStreamReader and then read the contents.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html